# How do I make a reusable SwiftUI View with a body I can fill in like List?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make a generic SwiftUI View that I can plug in and out of my controls. More than just passing it data though, I want to be able to pass in subviews like you would to a `List` like so:

```
List{
    Text("This works")
    Text("Hello World")
    Text("This works")
}

MyClass {
    Text("This works")
    Text("Hello World")
    Text("This works")
}
```

Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about declaring this class?

Comment: You'll have to investigate the ViewBuilder.

Comment: @kontiki Group wouldn't do this for him?

Comment: @matt You're right. Maybe I misunderstood the question. For the OP. Could you clarify what exactly is your goal? That is, in what way the existing Group, List, ScrollView, etc are not enough.

Comment: @kontiki Hi, I wanted to experiment with a List with my own styling. Things like being able to remove the separator lines or customize the sections (such as changing background color)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@ViewBuilder` property wrapper:

```swift
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    var content: () -> Content

    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView {
            Text("hello")
            Text("world")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want the content to be optional?

Comment: @rraphael I want to create a content that can be filled (Rectangle). Is there a way to conform to this protocol?