# How to customize the SwiftUI ViewBuilder

Tags: arrays, swiftui

There are some posts about SwiftUI Builder like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185101/how-do-i-make-a-reusable-swiftui-view-with-a-body-i-can-fill-in-like-list/57185300). So that I can embed my content like:

```
struct Container<Content>: View where Content: View {

  var content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }

  var body: some View {
    return content
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Container() {
      Text("Content 1").tag(0)
      Text("Content 2").tag(1)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if I don't pass the ViewBuilder in init. Instead I'd like to do something like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Container().buildContent {
      Text("Content 1").tag(0)
      Text("Content 2").tag(1)
    }
  }
}
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to mimic the **`TabView`**'s **`tabItem`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the `buildContent` function mutate the `Container`, but you can default to having a `Container` that just vends an `EmptyView`, and the use that as a springboard for creating a new `Container` with your desired content.

You could achieve that sort of API like this:

```swift
struct Container<Content>: View where Content: View {
    var content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        return content
    }
}

extension Container where Content == EmptyView {
    init() {
        self.content = EmptyView()
    }

    /// Return a new `Container` with the given `Content` builder.
    func buildContent<V : View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> V) -> Container<V> {
        Container<V>(content: content)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Container().buildContent {
            Text("Content 1").tag(0)
            Text("Content 2").tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need for `@escaping` in your example since the function `content` is called right there before the constructor ends. You would need that if you saved it and invoked it later